# Why can't I access my desktop after installing Lubuntu?

Tags: login, lubuntu, login-screen, logging

I installed Lubuntu 12.10 in my netbook through USB Drive. Now I cannot get access in my desktop after login. I can see only one thing on my screen.

```
Welcome to ubuntu 12.10(GNU/linux 3.5.0-17- generic i686,
0 packages can be updated
0 updates are security updates.
sumit@sumit-hp-mini:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you got into a shell instead of getting the desktop

```
sumit@sumit-hp-mini:~$
```

Try typing `startx` in order to start your X desktop. If that doesn't work - please add the command's output to your post (Since it is currently hard to know what is the specific reason you didn't get a desktop environment)